# Adding third party class in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to add PHRETS class to Drupal 8 (https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS). I did this in drupal 7 by simply including autoload.php file and calling the class name. But Drupal 8 doesn't allow this. It need to declare the classes in PSR-4 format. PHRETS has so many classes. Is there any other way around to call the class directly like below which I used for Drupal 7:

```
use PHRETS\Configuration;
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Composer Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_manager) module handle the autoload of Composer managed third party libraries. Usage of the module is covered in [its documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2405811).